# ng-repeat not showing null value

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have my controller set up like this:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.obj = ["MobilePhone",null,"HomePhone"];
}
```

and im using an ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
     <p ng-repeat="yeah in obj"> {{yeah}}</p>
</div>
```

and I need to show the empty space from the null value like this:

```
MobilePhone

HomePhone
```

but instead im getting this:

```
MobilePhone
HomePhone
```

Any help would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<p ng-repeat="yeah in obj"> {{yeah || '&nbsp;' }}</p>
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/63wWe/

Comment: Thank you! I didnt think about adding that you could add that inside the brackets